# Why doesn't scanf("%[^\n]s", text) print output?

Tags: c

```
char *text;
text = malloc(256);
printf("Enter a sentence:");
scanf("%[^\n]s", text);
printf("%s",text);
```

Why doesn't the `scanf` function work in this code?

I don't enter a sentence and immediately the program finished.

Comment: This works fine for me; how are you compiling/running this program

Comment: You will have to provide a full [mre] to get an answer. That piece of code should not exhibit the described behaviour by itself alone. BTW it should be `"%[^\n]"` without the `s`...

Comment: @SergeBallesta "it should be "%[^\n]" ..." --> why not suggest the equally good [`gets()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694036/why-is-the-gets-function-so-dangerous-that-it-should-not-be-used)?

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica: because my religion does not allow me to use (or advise) `gets` ;-) Yes, I know that `"%[^\n]"` is not better but I just wanted to tell OP not to use s after [], and felt too tired to explain why not controling size on input was bad and that only `fgets` or `%xxxs` or `%yyy[...]` should be used. May be I should have a coffee...

Comment: Yes - I too feel the  strain of the `scanf()` quagmire - time for a break.

Comment: @cat_software,  Who or what text suggested `"%[^\n]s"`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`scanf("%[^\n]s", text);` is worse than [`gets()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694036/why-is-the-gets-function-so-dangerous-that-it-should-not-be-used).  `text[]` remains unassigned if only `"\n"` entered <sup>*1</sup>, possible buffer overflow with no width limit.  The `s` in for format serves no purpose.

Instead use `fgets()` with its input limit.  Check return value.

```
#define N 256
char *text = malloc(N);
printf("Enter a sentence:");
if (fgets(test, N, stdin)) {
  test[strcspn(test, "\n")] = '\0';  // Lop off potential trailing \n
  printf("%s\n",text);
}
```

OP may also have trouble due to a prior `scanf()` calls that leaves a dangling `'\n'` in `stdin` that chokes on this `scanf("%[^\n]s"...`.  Avoid using `scanf()` at all until you know why it is weak.

Sigh - if you *must* stay with `scanf()`, use below which 1) uses a leading space to consume all prior white-space like left-over `'\n'`, 2) has a width limit and 3) tests the `scanf()` success.

```
if (scanf(" %255[^\n]", text) == 1) {  // No 's' in format.
  printf("%s\n",text);
}
```

---

<sup>*1</sup>  This explains the "I don't enter a sentence and immediately the program finished." as prior input did not consume a `'\n'` and OP's code does not either and so stops the scan.  Since OP's code did not consume the `'\n'` and `scanf()` did not return 1 (which OP's code failed to test), following unposted code certainly fell into *undefined behavior*.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that your program runs, but the console closes before you can see the result.

Try to modify to the following:

```
char *text;
text = malloc(256);
printf("Enter a sentence:");
scanf("%[^\n]s", text);
printf("%s",text);
system("pause");
```

Comment: Yes it works but Enter a sentence:É#© this sentences are printed. When i add the white spice scanf(" %[^\n]s", text); like that program works well. what is the problem i don't understand. Why i have to add white space

Comment: I don't understand your comment. Can you please elaborate more?

Comment: For example. when i write this function --scanf(" %[^\n]s",text);-- "There is a white space betwee  " and %-- program works well but when there is no space between them program directly write randomly and program finish. the thing i wanna say is why i add the white spice between them. my english language is bad sorry for that